# Обработка тела сообщения перед отправкой email Swift

Tags: swift

изучаю Swift, интересует возможность изменить текст перед отправкой Email, с [оф доки](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller) взял код, всё круто, но есть одно но, можно задать инициализирующий текст, а можно ли как-то перед нажатием на кнопку обработать полученный текст? Допустим просто добавить к нему пару символов, или ещё чего сделать, и отправить уже измененное сообщение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно нельзя, и об этом сказано по приведенной вами ссылке

> After presenting a mail compose view controller, the system ignores any attempts to modify the email using the methods of this class. The user can still edit the content of the email, but your app cannot. Therefore, always configure the fields of your email before presenting the view controller.

Comment: Окей, а то есть получается только через сторонние либы возможна такая вещь?

Comment: @antipups выходит так